# Joomla relative date

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a small problem. I need my Joomla site to show normal dates in an absolute way. I want it to say 'published on January 14, 2014' not 'published 3 hours ago' like it's now. I think template [Joomlart's Ja-Magz] has some overrides that I don't know how to remove, and they are really not quick with answering questions on their forum, so if anyone has any idea, it would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the dates are showing up, you need to look at the these template override files -

1. For dates showing up in category listings: /templates/ja-magz/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
2. For dates showing up on an article detail page: /templates/ja-magz/html/com_content/article/default.php